# In hive, how to generate array type data from a table

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with columns like:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bay: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- bay_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- section_id: long (nullable = true)
```

and for one id, there're many related addresses and related bay array( array type of hive parquet table). I want to generate a new table like:

```
id, array(related_address, related_array, ...)
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- address_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- bay: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- bay_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- section_id: long (nullable = true)
```

Currently, I turn DataFrame to RDD to collect related data:

```
dt.rdd.map(r=>{
  val id = r.getAs[String](1)
  val rest = (2 to columnLength).map(x=>r.get(x))
  (id, Row(rest: _*))
}.groupByKey().map(tuple=>Row(tuple._1, tuple._2.toSeq)
```

I get something like `Row[id, Array[related_address, related_array, ...]]`, then, I make a schema like `StructType(structTypeOfId +: ArrayType(relatedAddrType, ...))`. At last, I'll create needed DataFrame by the schema and RDD.

But how could I get needed schema just by hive? Method through RDD is very very slow!

Comment: What's the original schema (`dt.printSchema`) and what is the expected output ? Can you provide a small example with dummy values so that we understand a bit better your problem ?

Comment: I've changed question, and provide more details about the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found some solution for this question. Use hive build in UDF: `struct` and `collect_set`. 
`struct` will package all columns passed to it in a new struct, and then, you can use `collect_set` (or `collect_list` according to request) to build an array of the struct. Codes like:

```
select id, collect_set(struct(address, address_id, bay)) as Address from oriTable;
```

In old version, collect_set can't receive struct but only primitive column, but in new version it support struct.